# Find a selected item in a ListBox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Background: I have a list box that allows multiple selections.  There is a specific value in my List Box that, if selected, needs a separate code path to be run for it and all other selections go through another path.

Problem: I can't figure out how to correctly write it in VB.NET to make it work the way I imagine it.

Code:

```
    For Each Item As String In listbox1.SelectedItems
        If listbox1.SelectedItem = myValue Then
           Do this
        Else
           Do that
        End If
    Next
```

If I make multiple selections on my list the code doesn't work correctly. It only works correctly if myValue is the only selection in listbox1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the `listbox1` bound, and what type is `myValue`? Also, is this Winforms, or ASP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your iteration is wrong, you should use the Item value in your loop:

```
For Each Item As String In listbox1.SelectedItems
    If Item = myValue Then
       Do this
    Else
       Do that
    End If
Next
```

A For Each loop basically does the following: (Please excuse any syntax errors, my vb is rusty)

```
For index As Integer = 0 To listbox1.SelectedItems.Length
    Def Item = listbox1.SelectedItems[index]
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mataniko. That was exactly what I needed. Marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
For i = listbox1.Items.Count
    If listbox1.Items[i].IsSelected = True Then
       'Do this
    Else
       'Do that
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:
If ListBox1.SelectedItem = ("Km 1795.5 - 1796.3") Then
Form78.Show()
End If
If ListBox1.SelectedItem = ("Km 1796.6 - 1797.4") Then
Form79.Show()
End If
If ListBox1.SelectedItem = ("Km 1798.7 - 1799.0") Then
Form80.Show()
End If

Comment: Poorly written answer.